# Keep focus on specific tab in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

in a last stint to change from EI to Edge, I'm trying to do some focusing that doesn't work like I want it to.

The situation is something like this. Edge is open with several tabs for different pages. One of these pages is an intranet system where the pages contains a link which opens a popup.
In this popup the user has a button where they can create some docx files on a server. To do this, the button calls a new page (subpage1) through javascript (window.open) and the new page again calls another page (subpage2), which finally creates the document.
The later (subpage2) will close (windows.close) it's window on completion.

It all works like it should, with the little annoyance, that the "mother" windows in Edge will switch to the tab to the far right, instead of just staying on the user choosen tab.

Can I control which tab keeps or regains focus when a tab are closed in Edge and if so how?

Comment: In my test, if you close a newly opened window, it will return to the former chosen tab. Could you please provide a minimal code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**? Then I can have a test and see how to help. Besides, [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) can bring the window to the front. You can have a try.

Comment: Not sure I can provide a code snippet that can reproduce it, but I'll come up with something. Perhaps it can show the idea at least.